# How to simulate key press in a specific chrome tab\window

Tags: python, keypress, pyautogui

So I want to simulate key presses in a **SPECIFIC** window\chrome tab. For eg, with pyautogui:

```
import pyautogui as py

while True:
    py.press("1")
    py.press("space")
    py.press("4")
```

This works when I'm on a tab, but if I go to another tab, it will simulate the key presses there. I want it to only simulate key presses in a specific tab, even if I'm in another tab.
Is there a way to modify the above program to do this, or is there another pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: Pyautogui (and other modules) sends keys to system and system can send it only to active window or tab. It may need some module specific for your system to access directly some elements in browser. And if you want to automate some actions in broweser then maybe you should check [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, PyAutoGUI can't do this because it only blindly clicks on the screen at x, y coordinates. Unless you know the coordinates of the tab, you won't be able to put it in focus and send key presses to the window.

I recommend a library like Selenium for doing GUI automation in web browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It will select second tab. Like that, which tab we need we can select.

```
import pyautogui
whichtab = 2 
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl',f'{whichtab}')
```